# How do you import sentinel - 2 data in Earth engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel2

This is the code i have so far.

```
var roi = ee.FeatureCollection(polygon);
Map.addLayer(roi, {}, 'Turkey');
  
//Load Sentinel data
var image = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
filterDate('2019-04-01', '2019-04-10')

//Remove cloud contamination
.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))    
.filterBounds(roi)

//Visualise data
var visParamsTrue = {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min:0, max:2500 ,gamma:1.1};  
Map.addLayer(image.clip(roi), visParamsTrue, 'Sentinel 2019');
Map.centerObject(roi, 20);
```

I want to import sentinel - 2 data within the study region using Google Earth Engine.

This is just an example of the expected result -
[Sentinel data is imported within the vector points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRvau.jpg)

This is what i get -
[Sentinel data is not imported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bd58w.png)

How do i fix this?

The code above is taken from the youtube video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N_yJDMgRfik